# Search and display Sharepoint list through a web part

Tags: web-part, search, search-box

In our company we are beginning to create a knowledge base site for users to easily access information such as Client IDs.  My goal is to use the search box web part to search for either a client or client ID which is located in a SharePoint 2010 list. Once the user enters a client or client ID into the search box, it would populate the results under the search box. How do I go about creating this?

So far i have created the SharePoint list with 2 columns for client and client ID. I then added the search box web part, but am now unsure of how i would configure the web part to search the SharePoint list and populate on the home page. I'm assuming I would need to add the search core results web part in order to populate results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things you would need to do:

1. define a custom search scope that includes only the list you wish to
   search
2. Define a scope group that includes only the above scope
3. add your Search Web Part to the page
4. configure it to use the scope group above
5. Add the Core Results web part to the page.
6. Perform a Full Crawl on your site

If you need even more flexibility, the Search Results Web Part can be customized in several ways, from including additional properties to completely changing the way the results are shown.

oh, and don't forget to add the Search results paging web part :)

Comment: Thanks Dave! I'll see what I can put together. Another option is connecting the text filter web part to the list.